# Drawing a circle with inner box shadow

Tags: css

I want to draw few circle using inner box-shadow.

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJzgs/)

css

```
.circle {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border:1px solid #000;
```

}

How can i apply inner box-shadow in the circle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify `inset` for the inner shadow, the x and y displacement, the blurring and the color. Example:

```
box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 4px #000;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uJzgs/2/

For compatibility:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 4px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 4px #000;
box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 4px #000;
```

Comment: I am trying to get an uniform shawow from every side. its not uniform

Comment: @Shubendra: Then use 0 for the x and y displacement. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uJzgs/3/

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `radial-gradient`

```
.circle {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background: radial-gradient(#FFF 40%, #000);
}
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/za7b8/1

Comment: True, you can do this, but I think a good reason for using `box-shadow` instead would be that it has better browser support (IE9) and required fewer vendor prefixed variants, so less CSS code. Also, a gradient background may interfere if the OP wants an actual background image as well.